# Match_phrase query Error in Elasticsearch 2.4.1?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to match particular text so for that i am using Match_phrase option and in my mapping some fields are not analysed by default the analyser will be standard so for that i am passing analyser field in match_phrase query.

When i am using the below query it is showing an error:

```
POST data/_search
{ "size":50,
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {
    "term":{
        "region":"USA"

    }},
         {
        "match_phrase":{
  "university":"University of michigan",
  "analyzer": "standard"
        }
        },

         {
        "match_phrase":{
  "games":"football and basketball",
      "analyzer": "standard"
        }
        }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

The error is:

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "query_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?",
            "index": "data",
            "line": 13,
            "col": 3
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "data",
            "node": "9pSi8WYdRRuVrmLjWoGqcg",
            "reason": {
               "type": "query_parsing_exception",
               "reason": "[match] query parsed in simplified form, with direct field name, but included more options than just the field name, possibly use its 'options' form, with 'query' element?",
               "index": "data",
               "line": 13,
               "col": 3
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

When i remove the analyser in the match_phrase fields it is working fine.
May i know where the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of:

```
"match_phrase":{
  "university":"University of michigan",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

you should do:

```
"match_phrase":{
  "university":{
    "query": "University of michigan",
    "analyzer": "standard"
  }
}
```